# Android Spinner inflated in a fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu() restores to default selection after any selection

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I've this spinner bundled into option menu and uses a custom adapter! But every selection made it quickly auto selects the default(first) item! What could be the issue or where am I wrong in this one!

```
        @Override
          public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.category_menu, menu);
            MenuItem item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.action_more);
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_select);

            final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            item1.setVisible(false);

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

              @Override
              public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                  Category cat = (Category) spinner.getSelectedItem();
                  if (cat.getId() != activity.phelper.getCatId()) {
                    activity.phelper.putCatId(Integer.valueOf(cat.getId().toString()));
                    loadArticles(cat.getId());
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

              }
            });
          }
```

and this is the adapter initialization

```
          list = Category.getCategories(activity);
          adapter = new CategoyAdapter(activity, R.layout.spinner_normal, list);
```

Comment: throw a log at the start of your `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onItemSelected`, then see if something is causing your `onCreateOptionsMenu` to run again after `onItemSelected`

Comment: actually I have come to realize that I was invoking invalidateOptionsMenu in the method loadArticles(); and that was resetting the state of the option items! But glad I worked it out